# git-svn: re-link git-svn cloned repo to svn

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I have on my gitlab a git repo which was originally cloned using `git svn clone https://svn.url.com/project/trunk`. I used to `dcommit` to the svn as well as `git push` to the gitlab from my local copy. But now I have now lost the original local copy where I do the git-svn clone from.. I do `git clone` from my gitlab but now I lost the capability to fetch from the svn and dcommit again.. Is there any way I can restore it? I've never back up the .git/svn folder under the git directory... :(

Comment: Can't you use `git reset --hard HEAD~n` to go back the original version? Note: `n` is the times you committed locally, such as you made 2 commits before use `git push`, so you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~2` to restore the version you use `git svn clone`.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy.

Open up your git config (under `.git/config`)

and add the following to the end

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
      url = https://svn.url.com/
      fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

you can then git-fetch to relink all your git-svn revisions

P.S: if it takes too long and/or your revisions are too many, you can directly move your refs/remotes/git-svn to the last known svn-revision before doing the git-fetch
e.g:

`git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/heads/master`